# SSO for Facebook integration

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social

Is it possible to have Single Sign On feature for Facebook integration from other application?

As Facebook uses OAuth 2.0 it seems client and resource owners both needs to be authenticated as token have limited lifetime.

Reason I want to have this feature is for write operation resource owner (Facebook user) authentication seems good but to read or display summary of user/page stat it might be annoying for user to log on to social network.

I am using Java (Spring Social APIs).

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the `offline_access` [permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/)?

Answer (score 0):

the offline_access permission is probably you're best route.  This creates a long lasting token for the user that you can use.  Make sure you're not using it to do anything against the FB TOS or you'll probably get your app banned.

Comment: offline_access is no longer viable as it is getting removed on May 1st 2012.